# Correct place for rails app-wide method that will be accessible to before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I have a couple of methods being fired by each request by before_filter. I've tried putting these methods in several places but ended up using them in a file under lib and that being the only way that worked. Where is the correct place to put these methods? Ideally I'd like to automatically have these accessible to every controller w/o including anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the methods used by several controllers in the `ApplicationController`. If most requests must execute this `before_filter`, put it also in the `ApplicationController`, and you can ignore the filter for specific actions with `skip_before_filter`. An example is available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Comment: It was my understanding that controllers handle a request, and make data / functions available from your model. Wouldn't stuffing a non-request related method in a controller be going against one of the basic concepts of Rails?

Comment: @franklinstine If you think the code is not related to the request handling, and could be reused somewhere else, put it in a module or class in the lib folder, and call it from the `before_filter` in the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks @baldrick that's exactly how I have it now, I just wasn't sure if that was the best / most preferred option.